# Bootstrap 3 effects on % height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to know what are Bootstrap 3 effects on height, when using percentages values.

Here's a simple html:

```
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <p>This is a div! </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

and css:

```
body {
  padding-top: 100px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 5px solid green;
}

.content {
  border: 5px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Without bootstrap, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNDJX.png) is the result.

With bootstrap, the result changes to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuPV7.png) instead.

So, here's my guess:

Without using bootstrap, height: 100% will look up to the parent of .content and look for its height. So in this case, .content will end with height: 400px. And since there's a 100px padding-top in body, body will have to grow 100px larger, ending with 500px, in order to match .content.

With bootstrap, height: 100% will try to fill the parent, instead of looking at its height, so since there's a 100px padding-top, .content will end with height: 300px and body remain at 400px height.

Is this correct?

How would I be able to replicate what bootstrap does, without using bootstrap?

Thanks in advance! ^-^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size you see with Bootstrap is because it uses `box-sizing: border-box`, instead of the default value of `content-box`..

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

So, if don't want to use Bootstrap, but have the same sizing, just add the CSS to set the box-sizing to `border-box`.

[Codeply Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/kGpM9ZQZKB)

Comment: Ooh, I get it now. Since body's height is 400px and the padding-top is 100px, that means its actual height is just 300px (using border-box) right? So when .content looks for its parent's height, it will read the value 300px?